# Python common config module depends on individualle config files / how to inject vars into shared module

Tags: python, import, config, python-module

Hey maybe my approach is a little bit twisted but:
I have a python project in which multiple "programs" share some logic how the config is created and need mostly the same config but have slightly different logic
They have vars that change from "program" to "program".
But how the vars are used to create the final config is the same.

Folder structure is like this:

```
|-prog1
  |- vars.py
  |- config.py
  |- logic.py
|
|-prog2
  |- vars2.py
  |- config.py
  |- logic2.py
|
|-common
  |- common.py
```

so the config file looks like this:

```py
import vars
xxx = vars + something
```

the "logic" file:

```py
form config import xxx
def do_x(data=xxx)
```

I would love to be able to put the config.py in common because I change it often and I would be annoying to change it in every `prog` directory.

I could for sure make a factory and add to the globals or something but this feels wrong and I would lose the ability to have a nice IDE experience.

**So how do I "inject" the vars into the shared config module to use them in the same way as before but it is a shared file?**

Im sure they is some way to do it or to change the whole logic how the config is created.